# How to turn scrolling "one screen at a time" off with MS Comfort mouse 4500

Tags: windows-7, windows, intellimouse

Under Windows-7, my 4500 mouse scrolls way too fast with "old" `"one screen at a time"`  settings.

I tried to disable the scroll `"one screen at a time"`, but this function was no longer available with the Intellimouse drivers.

First, I tried to reset the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop: WheelScrollLines` from -1 to 10. But this value is reset to `-1` after a reboot.

I removed the Intellimouse software and with the "bare bones" mouse configuration tool, un-checked the scroll `"one screen at a time"`.

After saving and closing, nothing changed.
When I re-opened the mouse configuration tool, the scroll `"one screen at a time"` was reset to be checked!
In other words the new value was not saved correctly or was immediately overwritten to the old value (scroll 1 page).

How can I permanently set the mouse configuration to scroll, e.g., 3 lines instead of the one screen at a time?

I have not yet re-connected the new Iintellimouse 4500, since the Intellimouse drivers will hide the scroll `"one screen at a time"`.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the culprit. It was [Katmouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/), running in the background, which was preventing me from changing the scroll settings.